# How can I pass a string representation of an image to Cloudinary upload?

Tags: cloudinary, ng-file-upload

Is it possible to get an image from a client application (Angular using `ng-file-upload`) and pass this into a webApi controller to then upload to Cloudinary? 
Reading the docs it seems that the Cloudinary API expects to read the image directly from file/Amazon S3 bucket/internet location?

How can I pass the string representation of an image to cloudinary upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary allows you to upload using a BASE64 URI representation as well. For more information see: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203125741-Can-I-upload-using-DATA-URI-BASE64-

Direct upload can be established either based on the [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/cloudinary/pkg-cloudinary-jquery-file-upload) or ng-file-upload plugin. Both are demonstrated [in this sample project](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/tree/master/samples/photo_album).